# Selecting certain data from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I wondering if there is anyway that if I know one part of an ArryList that I can find out the other. The problem I'm running into is my limited knowledge of java.

I have the list set up as:

```
spotsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

The activity goes through and adds every spot(from a server) to the list in a forloop with PID and NAME as:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
spotsList.add(map);
```

Now is there a way I can get the name if I know the PID?

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a domain class instead of a `HashMap` to hold that data. If you did that you could easily search a collection for a particular value.

```
public class Spot {
    private final String pid;
    private final String name;

    public Spot(String pid, String name) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getters 
}
```

You'll want to add override `equals()` and `hashCode()` also.

And then use a map instead of a list:

```
Map<String,Spot> spots = new HashMap<String,Spot>();
spots.put(pid, new Spot(pid, name));
```

Then to find one:

```
Spot spot = spots.get(pid);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it underlines map and hashmap saying incorrect number of arguments. Also, how would I go about adding an override for equals() and hashcode()?

Comment: Make sure you import them first. For `equals()` and `hashCode()` check out the builders from Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

Comment: The Map and HashMap. If you did and you're still getting errors, what jdk version are you using?

Comment: Both are imported. How do I check jdk? I'm just using eclipse and don't remember changing the jdk so I guess the default

Comment: I also tried using map<string, spot> instead of just <spot> but that did not work either

Comment: Oops, I missed that, sorry. Try it the way I have it now.

Comment: Another question, didn't want to start a new thread, how would I send this between two activities? I tried in.putExtra("shared",shr_spots) where shr_spots is what you put in the example as spots and it gives me an error

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you expect the PIDs to be unique (given a PID you can find the corresponding name). So instead of a list of maps you should probably just use one map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Spot s : spots) map.put(s.id, s.name);
```

Retrieving a name from the pid is then simply a matter of:

```
String name = map.get(pid);
```

Comment: Thanks :D But when I posted the problem I simplified it by only using name and PID but 6 others that I would need to add to it. Would I go about that the same way?

Comment: The more specific your question, the best answers you will get! If all fields are linked to the pid, you could create a class that wraps the 6 fields and use a `Map<String, YourClass>` instead.

Comment: I tried using the class from below but got the error when I changed map<spot> to map<String,spot> even though it was saying it needed more  variables there.